# Calculating the value of radio buttons, select and check boxes

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

HI I am doing a menu for a pizza place (Leaning project) where one the user select the radio buttons  the the select buttons it calculations the total. Instance at the minute I a chose of three radio buttons small medium and large. and 3 select boxes. each time select box is chosen £1 will be added to the price of the given value of the chosen radio button. For instance if some selects the small radio button that's £4 then they select the next three select box's that's a total of £7 which should be displayed instantly on the screen on each selection. I haven't added the check boxes yet as I have noticed its not working. I got the original script from an on-line tutorial that worked when I tested. But after tying to modify it to suit it seems that the dive that displays the total price wont work.

```js
< body onload = 'hideTotal()' >
  < div id = "wrap" >
  < form action = ""
id = "pizzaform"
onsubmit = "return false;" >
  < div >
  < div class = "cont_order" >
  < fieldset >
  < legend > Make your Pizza! < /legend>
                <label >Size Of the Pizza</label > < br / >
  Small Pizza 7 "(£4)
                <label class='radiolabel'><input type="
radio "  name="
selectedpizza " value="
Round1 " onclick="
calculateTotal()
" />Round                  </label><br />
                 Large 11" (£6) < label class = 'radiolabel' > < input type = "radio"
name = "selectedpizza"
value = "Round2"
onclick = "calculateTotal()" / > Round < /label><br / >
  Midum 15 "(£8)
                <label class='radiolabel'><input type="
radio "  name="
selectedpizza " value="
Round3 " onclick="
calculateTotal()
" />Round                    </label><br />
                <br />
                
                <label >Sacuce</label>
         
                <select id="
sauce " name='sauce' onchange="
calculateTotal()
">
                <option value="
None ">Select Sacuce</option>
                <option value="
Enzo 's classic Sauce">Enzo'
s classic Sauce(£1) < /option>
                <option value="Spicy Tomato">Spicy Tomato(£1)</option >
  < /select>
                <br / >

  < label > Base < /label>
         
                <select id="base" name='base' onchange="calculateTotal()">
                <option value="None">Select Base</option >
  < option value = "Thin and cripy" > Thin and cripy(£1) < /option>
                <option value="Deep Pan">Deep Pan(£1)</option >
  < option value = "Stuffed Crust" > Stuffed Crust(£1) < /option>
                </select >
  < br / >

  < label > Cheese < /label>
         
                <select id="cheese" name='cheese' onchange="calculateTotal()">
                <option value="None">Select cheese</option >
  < option value = "Mozzarella" > Mozzarella(£1) < /option>
                <option value="Reduced Fat">Reduced Fat(£1)</option >
  < /select>
                <br / >

  < div id = "totalPrice" > < /div>
                
                </fieldset >

  < /div>
            
        </div >
  < /form>
 </div > <!--End of wrap-->

  < script language = "javascript"
type = "text/javascript" >
  /*
  This source is shared under the terms of LGPL 3
  www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html

  You are free to use the code in Commercial or non-commercial projects
  */

  //Set up an associative array
  //The keys represent the size of the Pizza
  //The values represent the cost of the Pizza i.e A 15" Pizza cost's £8
  var pizza_prices = new Array();
pizza_prices["Round1"] = 4;
pizza_prices["Round2"] = 6;
pizza_prices["Round3"] = 8;

var sacuce_prices = new Array();
sacuce_prices["None"] = 0;
sacuce_prices["Enzo's classic Sauce"] = 1;
sacuce_prices["Spicy Tomato"] = 1;

var base_prices = new Array();
base_prices["None"] = 0;
base_prices["Thin and cripy"] = 1;
base_pricess["Deep Pan"] = 1;
base_pricess["Stuffed Crust"] = 1;

var cheese_prices = new Array();
cheese_prices["None"] = 0;
cheese_prices["Mozzarella"] = 1;
cheese_prices["Reduced Fat"] = 1;


// getPizzaSizePrice() finds the price based on the size of the Pizza.
// Here, we need to take user's the selection from radio button selection
function getPizzaSizePrice() {
  var pizzaSizePrice = 0;
  //Get a reference to the form id="pizzaform"
  var theForm = document.forms["pizzaform"];
  //Get a reference to the Pizza the user Chooses name=selectedPizza":
  var selectedPizza = theForm.elements["selectedpizza"];
  //Here since there are 4 radio buttons selectedPizza.length = 4
  //We loop through each radio buttons
  for (var i = 0; i < selectedPizza.length; i++) {
    //if the radio button is checked
    if (selectedPizza[i].checked) {
      //we set PizzaSizePrice to the value of the selected radio button
      //i.e. if the user choose the 8" Pizza we set it to 6
      //by using the pizza_prices array
      //We get the selected Items value
      //For example pizza_prices["Round2".value]"
      pizzaSizePrice = pizza_prices[selectedPizza[i].value];
      //If we get a match then we break out of this loop
      //No reason to continue if we get a match
      break;
    }
  }
  //We return the PizzaSizePrice
  return PizzaSizePrice;
}


function getPizzaSacucePrice() {
  var pizzaSaucePrice = 0;
  //Get a reference to the form id="cakeform"
  var theForm = document.forms["pizzaform"];
  //Get a reference to the select id="sauce"
  var selectedSauce = theForm.elements["sauce"];

  //set pizzaSauce Price equal to value user chose
  //For example sauce_prices
  pizzaSaucePrice = sauce_prices[selectedSauce.value];

  //finally we return pizzaSaucePrice
  return PizzaSaucePrice;
}

function getBasePrice() {
  var pizzaBasePrice = 0;
  //Get a reference to the form id="pizzaform"
  var theForm = document.forms["pizzaform"];
  //Get a reference to the select id="base"
  var selectedBauce = theForm.elements["base"];

  //set pizzaBase Price equal to value user chose
  //For example base_prices
  pizzaBaseePrice = base_prices[selectedBase.value];

  //finally we return pizzaSaucePrice
  return pizzaBasePrice;
}

function getCheesePrice() {
  var pizzaCheesePrice = 0;
  //Get a reference to the form id="pizzaform"
  var theForm = document.forms["pizzaform"];
  //Get a reference to the select id="cheese"
  var selectedCheese = theForm.elements["cheese"];

  //set pizzaCheese Price equal to value user chose
  //For example cheese_prices
  pizzaBaseePrice = cheese_prices[selectedSauce.value];

  //finally we return pizzaCheesePrice;
  return PizzaCheesePrice;
}


function calculateTotal() {
  //Here we get the total price by calling our function
  //Each function returns a number so by calling them we add the values they return together
  var pizzaPrice = getPizzaSizePrice() + getSacucePrice() + getBasePrice() + getCheesePrice();

  //display the result
  var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
  divobj.style.display = 'block';
  divobj.innerHTML = "Total Price For the Pizza £" + pizzaPrice;

}

function hideTotal() {
  var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
  divobj.style.display = 'none';
}

< /script>
```

```html
<body onload='hideTotal()'>
  <div id="wrap">
    <form action="" id="pizzaform" onsubmit="return false;">
      <div>
        <div class="cont_order">
          <fieldset>
            <legend>Make your Pizza!</legend>
            <label>Size Of the Pizza</label>
            <br />Small Pizza 7"(£4)
            <label class='radiolabel'>
              <input type="radio" name="selectedpizza" value="Round1" onclick="calculateTotal()" />Round</label>
            <br />Large 11"(£6)
            <label class='radiolabel'>
              <input type="radio" name="selectedpizza" value="Round2" onclick="calculateTotal()" />Round</label>
            <br />Midum 15"(£8)
            <label class='radiolabel'>
              <input type="radio" name="selectedpizza" value="Round3" onclick="calculateTotal()" />Round</label>
            <br />
            <br />

            <label>Sacuce</label>

            <select id="sauce" name='sauce' onchange="calculateTotal()">
              <option value="None">Select Sacuce</option>
              <option value="Enzo's classic Sauce">Enzo's classic Sauce(£1)</option>
              <option value="Spicy Tomato">Spicy Tomato(£1)</option>
            </select>
            <br />

            <label>Base</label>

            <select id="base" name='base' onchange="calculateTotal()">
              <option value="None">Select Base</option>
              <option value="Thin and cripy">Thin and cripy(£1)</option>
              <option value="Deep Pan">Deep Pan(£1)</option>
              <option value="Stuffed Crust">Stuffed Crust(£1)</option>
            </select>
            <br />

            <label>Cheese</label>

            <select id="cheese" name='cheese' onchange="calculateTotal()">
              <option value="None">Select cheese</option>
              <option value="Mozzarella">Mozzarella(£1)</option>
              <option value="Reduced Fat">Reduced Fat(£1)</option>
            </select>
            <br />

            <div id="totalPrice"></div>

          </fieldset>

        </div>

      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <!--End of wrap-->
```

Can any one help? Also I plan on give the user a choice of 10 toppings using check boxes is there a way of limiting the user so they can only choose 4 out of the choice of 10?

Comment: Please check your spelling on 'sauce' and 'medium'. Also, your first block of code has unnecessary spaces `< div >` and newlines.

Answer (score 0):

Data attributes would work well for both purposes.

## Counting the total

Use `data-price` on radios, checkboxes and options:

```
<form id="my-form">
  <input type="radio" data-price="100" name="radio">Add 1GBP
  <input type="radio" data-price="200" name="radio">Add 2GBP

  <select>
    <option>Select something</option>
    <option data-price="300">Add 3GB</option>
    <option data-price="400">Add 4GB</option>
  </select>
</form>

Total: <span id="my-total"></span>
```

Then count them on every page load and form change with jQuery:

```
$('#my-form').on('change', function(){
  update_total();
});
function update_total(){
  var tot = 0;
  var price = 0;
  $('#my-form input:checked').each(function(){
    price = $(this).data('price');
    if(price > 0){
      tot += price;
    }
  });
  $('#my-form select').each(function(){
    price = $("option:selected", this).data('price');
    if(price > 0){
      tot += price;
    }
  });
  $('#my-total').html(tot);
}
update_total();
```

## Limiting checkboxes

Use `data-max-check` to define the maximum amount of checkboxes that can be checked in a given container:

```
<div data-max-check="4">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox">...
```

Then stop the user from selecting more than the maximum with jQuery:

```
$('[data-max-check] input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function(e){
  var $parent = $(this).closest('[data-max-check]');
  var max = $parent.data('max-check');
  var chk = $parent.find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').size();
  if(chk > max){
    alert('You can only select up to ' + max);
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

## Demo

You can see both in action here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gunrmpv8/4/)

Comment: this won't support decimal value. Can you please modify your answer which supports decimal values in the attribute.

Comment: @acmsohail It is much easier to work with units (e.g. `123` instead of `1.23`) and divide by 100 _only_ for display purposes.

Comment: I don't recommend this divide option as it will be confusing many other scenarios. Is there any other way to use the decimal value in the data-attribute and calculate the total? please help

Comment: @acmsohail The divide approach is recommended and widely used. https://husobee.github.io/money/float/2016/09/23/never-use-floats-for-currency.html